# Javascript filter array of objects by class

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

in this array of objects

```
array = [
0: foo1{name: "111", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0, …}
1: foo1 {name: "222", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0, …}
2: foo2 {name: "3", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0, …}
3: foo2 {name: "5", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0, …}
4: foo3 {name: "22", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0, …}
5: foo1 {name: "444", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0, …}
]
```

exist a method to filter by class of object?.
example :

```
let arr = array.filter( foo => foo === foo1) ;
```

// expected output:

```
arr = [ 
0: foo1 {name: "111", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0, …}
1: foo1 {name: "222", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0, …}
2: foo1 {name: "444", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0, …}
]
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mkeg2b
thx

Comment: please add a valid data structure.

Comment: sorry, added stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

> The instanceof operator tests to see if the prototype property of a
> constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object. The
> return value is a boolean value.

```
let arr = array.filter(foo => foo instanceof foo1)
```

```js
let arr = []

class foo1 {
  constructor(name, value) {
    this.name = '',
      this.value = 0
  }
}

class foo2 {
  constructor(name, value) {
    this.name = '',
      this.value = 0
  }
}

class foo3 {
  constructor(name, value) {
    this.name = '',
      this.value = 0
  }
}

let bar1 = new foo1();
let bar2 = new foo2();
let bar3 = new foo3();

arr.push(bar1, bar1, bar1, bar1, bar2, bar3, bar2, bar1);

document.write('check in browser console')
console.log(arr.filter(foo => foo instanceof foo1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const 
    array = [{ foo1: { name: "111", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0 } }, { foo1: { name: "222", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0 } }, { foo2: { name: "3", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0 } }, { foo2: { name: "5", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0 } }, { foo3: { name: "22", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0 } }, { foo1: { name: "444", energy: 0, capacity: 0, comsuption: 0, season: 0 } }]
    
let result = array.filter(o=>o.foo1); 

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `constructor.name` to filter the array based on constructor.

```
let arr = array.filter(foo => foo.constructor.name === "foo1")
```